# Drawing lines between markers in OpenLayers

Tags: php, openlayers, openstreetmap

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map("Map");
var maplin         = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
map.addLayer(maplin);

var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
map.addLayer(markers);
var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Overlay");
$.each(myVariable, function(i,myVariable){


        var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
            new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point( myVariable.lon,myVariable.lati ).transform(fromProjection, toProjection),

            {description:myVariable.description} ,
            {externalGraphic: 'img/marker.png', graphicHeight: 25, graphicWidth: 21, graphicXOffset:-12, graphicYOffset:-25  }
        );
        vectorLayer.addFeatures(feature);

        map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

        map.setCenter(feature, zoom);

    });
```

this is the code i used for show the locations on my map i used ajax to get the locations from the database 
but now i want to draw lines between those locations

Comment: _openstreetmap_ tag?

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** Your code suggest openlayer map and based on that I express code example below.

Here is an example:

```
var lineLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Line Layer"); 

map.addLayer(lineLayer);                    
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(lineLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Path));                                     
var points = new Array(
   new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lon1, lat1),
   new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lon2, lat2)
);

var line = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(points);

var style = { 
  strokeColor: '#0000ff', 
  strokeOpacity: 0.5,
  strokeWidth: 5
};

var lineFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(line, null, style);
lineLayer.addFeatures([lineFeature]);
```

Here, map is your map object and *lon* and *lat* are float values.